# Unable to Generate .pfx File For Azure App

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, des

We are trying to update an SSL certificate in our Azure Web App. Accordingly to the [Private Certificate Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#private-certificate-requirements) we need to use triple DES for a private key now. Here's are steps that I'm doing:

1. Generate private key on my PC using triple DES:

   openssl genrsa -des3 -out privatekey.key 2048
2. Generate csr:

   openssl req -new -key privatekey.key -out mycsr.csr
3. Re-key certificate on Godaddy Portal.
4. Using new crt-file generate a pfx:

   openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privatekey.key -in mycert.crt

Unfortunately, generated certificate is not accepted by Azure portal. I'm getting an error message "The password is incorrect, or the certificate is not valid".

Comment: The encryption of the file created by `genrsa` has no effect at all on the encryption of the PFX/PKCS12, plus from your link it appears they want _all_ the PFX encryption 3DES not just the privatekey. If you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1 or lower, it defaults to 3DES for privatekey but not certbag, so for that specify `-certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES`. If you are using 3.0 it defaults to PBES2+SHA256+AES256 for both privatekey and certbag, so specify both `-certpbe` and `-keypbe`. (fixed) PS: as that links says, you need to include the intermediate aka chain and root certs also.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 uses a yescrypt hashing algorythm. Try to generate the pfx on

Comment: on an older Ubuntu or Debian System